# Why it fails to load the referenceImage?

Tags: swiftui, arkit, apple-vision, visionos

Currently, I try to test the ImageTrackingProvider with the Apple Vision Pro. I started with some basic code:

```
import Foundation
import RealityKit
import ARKit

@MainActor class ARKitViewModel: ObservableObject{
    private let session = ARKitSession()
    private let imageTracking = ImageTrackingProvider(referenceImages: ReferenceImage.loadReferenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR"))
    
    func runSession() async {
        do{
            try await session.run([imageTracking])
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func processUpdates() async {
        for await _ in imageTracking.anchorUpdates{
            print("test")
        }
    }
}
```

I only have one picture in the AR folder. I added the size an I have no error messages in the AR folder.
[image]

As I am trying to run the application with the vision Pro, I receive following error:

```
ar_image_tracking_provider_t <0x28398f1e0>: Failed to load reference image <ARReferenceImage: 0x28368f120 name="IMG_1640" physicalSize=(1.350, 2.149)> with error: Failed to add reference image.
```

It finds the image, but there seems to be a problem with the loading. I tried the jpeg and the png format.

I do not understand why it fails to load the ReferenceImage.

I use Xcode Version 15.3 beta 3

I access the class ARKitViewModel via the Immersive View:

```
struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @StateObject var arKitVM = ARKitViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            
        }
        .task {
            await arKitVM.runSession()
        }
        .task {
            await arKitVM.processUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does an actor named ReferenceImage come from?

Comment: `...there seems to be a problem with the loading`, but you don't show any code relating to that, why?
Note you use `class ARKitViewModel: ObservableObject`, but you don't publish anything.
Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Comment: I added the code to my question that shows how I access the ARKitViewModel class. This code seems to work perfectly. The problem seems to be linked to the referenceImage. It finds the added image (name of the file, width, height), but cannot load it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems to be a know issue in visionsos 1.0. Nevertheless, it works if you are ignoring the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference image has incorrect `physicalSize=(1.350, 2.149)` because you used comma `,` separator instead of dot `.` separator. You've probably changed the decimal separator in macOS settings and it probably doesn't match the ARKit / RealityKit metric system. In the Xcode Inspector, you need to specify the physical size of the image as 1.35 x 2.15 meters. Also, the minimum image size of your JPEG or PNG must be at least 480x480 pixels.

Moreover, since you're running a session with an image tracking provider, you need to use a `NSWorldSensingUsageDescription` key (set it in info.plist tab) to indicate that your app needs access to the world-sensing data.

Comment: I changed the separator, but it seems that this was not the problem.
The minimum image size of the pictures is already greater than 480x480. And I already set the key in info.plist. I do not understand why the system has problems to load the image. Unfortunately, the error message is not detailed enough.

Comment: Have you tried other reference pictures? Have you tried it in Xcode 15.2 release? P.S. Xcode tells me that the min size is still 480x480 pix.

Comment: Yes, I tried different pictures and formats. First I had also the 480x480 error message. I changed the picture and the size and the error message closed. So I guess that this should not be the problem. 
I made a test on 15.2 and I receive the same error.